# Can't open .png file in pygame

Tags: python, image, pygame

I have made a pong game with powerups and it works in windows, but in linux, it gives me the error "Can't open paddle.png".

Again, it works in Windows, but not Linux.

Sample of the code: -- MEANS PART OF THE CODE, NOT WHOLE THING

```
import pygame, sys, time
from random import *

pygame.init()

disw = 640
dish = 480
black = (  0,  0,  0)
white = (255,255,255)
green = (  0,255,  0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((disw, dish))
pygame.display.set_caption("Super-Pong", "S-P")
Clock = pygame.time.Clock()

playerOne = pygame.image.load("paddle.png")
playerOneX = 50
playerOneY = 180

playerTwo = pygame.image.load("paddle.png")
playerTwoX = 590
playerTwoY = 180
```

Problem: Won't open .png files in linux for python program.

Tried: Running in Windows, worked in Windows.

They are in the same directory as well.

I've also tried making it paddle.jpg and a couple other formats, no dice.

My error:

```
[hunter@localhost ~]$ su -
Password: 
Last login: Sun Nov 30 16:56:52 EST 2014 on pts/0
[root@localhost ~]# python /home/hunter/Documents/realprojects/superpong/Super-Pong.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hunter/Documents/realprojects/superpong/Super-Pong.py", line 16, in <module>
    playerOne = pygame.image.load("paddle.png")
pygame.error: Couldn't open paddle.png
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you tell a function in a Python library to load a file with a relative path, such as `"paddle.png"`, it'll look in the current working directory (CWD). And if you start a Python program while the CWD is the home directory of user `root`, Pygame will look for image files in the home directory of user `root` unless otherwise specified.

To change where Pygame looks for images, you need to do one of three things:

- Change the current working directory (`cd`) to the directory containing `paddle.png` before running `Super-Pong.py`. Python for Windows automatically does this when you double-click a Python program, which is why it worked in Windows.
- In the program, change the current working directory to the directory containing `paddle.png`, which is likely the same directory containing the program (`Super-Pong.py`). The path to the program is passed as `sys.argv[0]`, so try this: `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))`
- In the program, add the path to the file. Again, assuming `paddle.png` is in the same folder, try this: `playerOne = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "paddle.png"))`

(Why `su -` anyway? A game shouldn't need to run as the superuser.)

Comment: Thank you! And su - in fedora means superuser login, which allows you to access any command and any folder.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `su` here, since (as far as I can see) the Python application is within your own `home`. `su` should generally only be used if your own user does not have the right privileges, which in most cases, it should have.

Comment: I just typed it in so I wouldn't have to later if I needed it.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late, but for anyone who is still experiencing this problem today, try to add a number to your image name (for example paddle1.png). I know it seems weird, but it actually fixed it for me for some reason, it might not fix it for you though...

Comment: It would be nice to have some additional details.

Comment: This solution is really weird. It should work without numbers in the filename as well, so the reason for your problems was most likely something else.