# Pygame images won't load anymore

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, pygame

Since I started this I've had char.png in the same folder as my .py file **not** a subfolder and it would load my images but when I added in the ability to move left and right, now I get an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "C:\Users\Shiloh\Google Drive\Python\Platformer\main.py", line 25, in <module>
    characterSprite = pygame.image.load('char.png')
pygame.error: Couldn't open char.png
```

I've gone back, removed everything I added since it was working and it still won't load the images anymore. I have not moved any files, I've just simply updated them. I've searched and tried the answers previously given on here but none of them have seemed to work in my sitation. Thanks in advance.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

#Window Resolution
display_width = 800
display_height = 450
gameResolution = pygame.display.set_mode( (display_width,display_height) )

#Window Title
pygame.display.set_caption('Bubble Bobble')

#Colors
colorRed = (255,0,0)
colorOrange = (255,160,96)
colorYellow = (255,216,0)
colorGreen = (0,255,0)
colorBlue = (0,0,255)
colorPurple = (235,193,255)
colorBlack = (0,0,0)
colorWhite = (255,255,255)

gameClock = pygame.time.Clock()
characterSprite = pygame.image.load('char.png')
def sprite(x,y):
        gameResolution.blit(characterSprite,(x,y))
x = (display_width * 0.5)
y = (display_height * 0.5)
x_change = 0


crashed = False
while not crashed:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        crashed = True
                        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                                        x_change = -5
                                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                                        x_change = 5
                        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                                        x_change = 0
        x += x_change
                #print(event) #Prints to console
        gameResolution.fill(colorWhite)
        sprite(x,y)
        pygame.display.update() #You can also use pygame.display.flip()
        gameClock.tick(60) #Sets the value of the FPS

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: are you sure its within the same directory that your main.py is being executed in?

Comment: Have no idea why it quit working, but you can probably workaround the issue by getting the directory the .py file is in with `mydir = os.path.dirname(__file__)` and then using `pygame.image.load(os.path.join(mydir, 'char.png'))` to load the image.

Comment: Yes @awbemauler, I've even triple checked.

Comment: @martineau 
mydir = os.path.dirname(C:\Users\Shiloh\Google Drive\Python\Platformer)
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I suggested you use `os.path.dirname(__file__)`, not a literal path.

Comment: I imported os, mydir = os.path.dirname(__file__) NameError: name '__file__' is not defined

Comment: @ColdHands **__file__** not just file

Comment: @awbemauler I did use __file__, it just doesn't show that in the log.

Comment: @ColdHands https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/#file

Comment: So an absolute path still doesnt work? ie; `C:\Users\Shiloh\Google Drive\Python\Platformer\char.png`

Comment: @ColdHands read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767129/how-to-have-an-image-appear-in-python-pygame) the answer says `your other problem is that your pyimage doesn't seem to be built with png support`

Comment: @awbemauler C:/Users/Shiloh/Google Drive/Python/Platformer/char.png works but not just simply char.png. Will this be alright if I eventually make this into a .exe and send it to people?

Comment: @ColdHands no because not everyone has that absolute path. change your png to bmp, ie; `py.image.load('char.bmp')`

Comment: @awbemauler pygame.error: Couldn't open char.bmp, I got the .png to load when I used the absolute path. Same for the .bmp. I swear the .py and the images are in the EXACT SAME file. I could literally screenshot it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think with python 3.x, for `__file__` you have to wrap that in quotes. so

```
mydir = os.path.dirname('__file__')
pygame.image.load(os.path.join(mydir, 'char.png'))
```

which should fix the problem.

if it doesnt, the chosen answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27218125/cant-open-png-file-in-pygame) mentions the issue with permissions. If you run the program as root, it will start in the home directory. Which is possible that that may be the issue, and you weren't having a problem using the absolute path. So, if you are running it as root... stop it.

You can tell if you are in the wrong current working directory by using this

`print (os.getcwd())`

or current file

`print (os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__')))`

Comment: It still can't find char.png or char.bmp. Even if I put it into a subfolder (ex. assets/img/char.bmp) it still doesn't find it. The only way it's found it so far is to do C:/Users/...

Comment: then the issue is most likely you're running it as admin, or youre in the wrong current working directory. try to print out your path and see if it matches up with where it should be.

Comment: They both print C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++, how do I change the working directory then?

os.chdir('char.png') like this?

Comment: no. you cant change your directory to a picture in a relative path. what does `print (os.path.dirname('__file__')` print out?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shiloh\Google Drive\Python\Platformer\main.py", line 52
    gameResolution.fill(colorWhite)
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: did you add that extra paranthesis at the end? `print (os.path.dirname('__file__'))` either way, just do `os.chdir('C:\Users\Shiloh\Google Drive\Python\Platformer\')`

Comment: os.chdir('C:/Users/Shiloh/Google Drive/Python/Platformer/') works! :D
Is this is perm. fix? Like how I asked earlier if I make this an .exe and send it to others will it continue to function properly? I really don't understand how this got changed in the first place lol.

Comment: No its a temporary fix. when you distribute it, all the files will be within that exe and it will execute it from its cwd (current working directory). The code you had before should work.

Comment: So when I compile it into an .exe I just get rid of the os.chdr?

Comment: yep. `characterSprite = pygame.image.load('char.png')` _should_ work as the exe will execute whatever is within that executable file.